# InvocationError while running flake8 in tox.ini

Tags: python-3.x, tox, flake8

It looks like I can't pass the relative nor absolute path to the folder that should be checked by flake8 inside the tox.ini file.

After performing a code in the shell:

```
flake8 tests/
```

Result is correct:

```
tests/unit\test.py:17:91: E501 line too long (93 > 90 characters)
```

But the same command started by tox by typing into the command prompt:

```
tox
```

results with:

```
py38 installed: flake8==3.9.2,mccabe==0.6.1,pycodestyle==2.7.0,pyflakes==2.3.1
py38 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='64'
py38 run-test: commands[0] | flake8 tests/
tests/unit\test.py:17:91: E501 line too long (93 > 90 characters)
ERROR: InvocationError for command 'C:\Users\48796\PycharmProjects\learningTests\.tox\py38\Scripts\flake8.EXE' tests/ (exited with code 1)
_______________________________________________________ summary _______________________________________________________
ERROR:   py38: commands failed
```

So the command is executed properly and then runs into an error. As you can see in the third row - the command is identical.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because `flake8` detected errors in your code it exits nonzero

when tox detects a command exiting nonzero it presents an `InvocationError`

everything is working as intended :)

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer and a tox core dev

Comment: Correct! When there is no single error over code investigated by flake8, the command results with 0.  Thank you for your help

Comment: What about when there are multiple commands. How does one get the output of say a linter and unit tests when execution stops after the first failure. I want them all to run, and to report any failures at the end. When ignoring nonzero exit code the final result is "ok" despite errors.

Comment: within a single env that's not possible

Comment: Hi @AnthonySottile can you tell me the config options available for `flake8` when running it from `tox` using a `pyproject.toml`? Can I put the `flake8` line length config in the `pyproject.toml` somehow? Or does `tox` have to have access to the `flake8` settings from it's `tox.ini`, in which case, if I'm feeding `tox.ini` from `pyproject.toml` can I have a section in the `tox.ini` text specially for `flake8` or do I have to use a command line option in the `flake8` invocation in `commands` in the `tox.ini`?

Comment: @NeilG that's unrelated to this Q&A -- if you have another question open another question

Answer (score 0):

I will double check the exact error message when I am at a PC, but you totally expect `tox` to fail when one of the commands in one environment is failing.

If you just want to check the output, but the command should succeed even when there are problems, you need to prepend the command with a dash `-`.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Anthony's comment was enough for me to solve this issue :)